# How do I adjust this custom <li> content as intended

Tags: html, css, html-lists, bullet

[image: 1]

Above is a mockup of the content that I am trying to replicate.

Here is what I have right now:

**[image: 2]**

below are my `<ul>` and `<li>` with CSS but I cannot exactly replicate what is in the mockup even if I use padding or margin:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#b1::before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #B1B1B1;
}

#b2::before {
  content: '|';
  color: #B1B1B1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="b1">Introduction</li>
  <li id="b2"></li>
  <li id="b1">Disclaimers</li>
  <li id="b2"></li>
  <li id="b1">Preservation of Immunities</li>
  <li id="b2"></li>
  <li id="b1">General</li>
</ul>
```

looking for another way to edit the CSS that is not padding or margin to get the design I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is not intended using symbols you need to create circle and lines to create this effect.

Comment: and that is why I am looking for advice on an alternative

Comment: Start by writing valid HTML - IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Using a border on an absolutely positioned pseudo element for the line parts would probably make a lot more sense, than inserting the `|` character - you'll have much better control over the line length.

Comment: Do you only need this on a solid color background, or does it have to work on any kind of background (image, gradients, whatever)? If the former, you could just place one "line" over the whole height of the UL, and use list bullets with a white rounded border for the "cutouts"

Comment: This should help: https://dev.to/peterc/how-to-create-joined-bulletpoint-lists-with-css-bbc-news-style-1eem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css";
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  row-gap: 16px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left: 8px;
  align-items: center;
}

li::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: gray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white;
}

li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 6px);
  left: -8px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="b1">Introduction</li>
  <li id="b1">Disclaimers</li>
  <li id="b1">Preservation of Immunities</li>
  <li id="b1">General</li>
</ul>
```